# Как завершить цикл while (cin >> word), где word является типом string?

Tags: c++

Программа выводит отдельно каждое слово из введенного предложения и в конце должна написать "Все слова прочитаны!", но она не выводит эту строку, потому что цикл бесконечный, как сделать его конечным, чтобы на терминал выводилось "Все слова прочитаны!", когда каждое слово из предложения уже было выведено.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
string word;
    while ( cin >> word )
        cout << "Прочитано слово: " << word << "\n";
    cout << "Все слова прочитаны! \n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: CTRL+D или CTRL+Z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [`stringstream`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) для этого.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    string text;
    getline(cin, text);

    stringstream ss(text);
    string word;

    while (ss >> word) {
        cout << "Прочитано слово: " << word << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Все слова прочитаны! \n";

    return 0;
}
```